# Javascript constructor method returning something different than expected

Tags: javascript

```
function Plant() {
  this.country = "Mexico"
  this.isOrganic = true;
}

function Fruit(fName, fColor) {
  this.name = fName;
  this.color = fColor;
}

Fruit.prototype = new Plant();

var abanana = new Fruit("Banana", "Yellow")
console.log(abanana.constructor)
```

So in my code, I was trying to play around with prototype inheritance. Each time I created a new instance of Fruit (var aFruit = new Fruit ()), the new instance’s prototype is assigned the prototype from the Fruit constructor, which is Fruit.prototype.

So why is abanana.constructor 
not

```
[function: Fruit]
```

but

```
[function: Plant]?
```

I thought this was what the constructor method does:

> Moreover, all objects that inherit from another object also inherit a constructor property. And this constructor property is simply a property (like any variable) that holds or points to the constructor of the object.

Comment: No, the constructor property '[returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems with that code:

1. Using `new Plant()` to create the `Fruit.prototype` is a sadly-common anti-pattern; instead, use `Object.create` and call `Plant` from within `Fruit`. It doesn't matter a lot in your specific code, but it would matter if you wanted to derive something from `Fruit`, or if you wanted to make `country` an argument to `Plant`.
2. You need to set `constructor` on `Fruit.prototype` if you want it to point to `Fruit`.

So:

```
function Plant() {
  this.country = "Mexico"
  this.isOrganic = true;
}

function Fruit(fName, fColor) {
  Plant.call(this);                               // **
  this.name = fName;
  this.color = fColor;
}

Fruit.prototype = Object.create(Plant.prototype); // **
Fruit.prototype.constructor = Fruit;              // **
```

Of course, as of ES2015, we have `class` syntax, which you can use today with a transpiler (or if you only need to support current versions of Chrome and Firefox):

```
class Plant {
    constructor() {
        this.country = "Mexico";
        this.isOrganic = true;
}

class Fruit extends Plant {
    constructor(fName, fColor) {
        super();
        this.name = fName;
        this.color = fColor;
    }
}
```

> I thought this was what the constructor method does:
>
> > Moreover, all objects that inherit from another object also inherit a constructor property. And this constructor property is simply a property (like any variable) that holds or points to the constructor of the object.

`constructor` isn't a method, it's a property that refers to the function that the `prototype` object is related to. JavaScript itself doesn't use `constructor` for anything at all, but does define that for all functions that have a `prototype` property, when the function is first created, the object that `prototype` property points to will have a `constructor` property pointing back at the function. But since you *replace* the value of `prototype` with a reference to a different object, you have to update the `constructor` property so it points back to the correct function again (if you want to be thorough, which is for the best — even though *JavaScript* doesn't use it, it doesn't mean that libraries don't use it).

---

On really old browsers, you may have to shim `Object.create`. It can't be completely shimmed, but it can be sufficient for the above:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(p, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw new Error("The second argument of Object.create cannot be shimmed.");
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = p;
        return new ctor;
    };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean derive something from fruit?

Comment: @Jwan622: The same way you've derived `Fruit` from `Plant`.

Comment: Did I derive something? I just set Fruit's prototype object to the plant object?

Comment: @Jwan622: That's deriving, to the extent the word means anything in JavaScript.